# Twitter Bootstrap - input fields inside container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am revisiting [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and testing out input fields nested in `container-fluid` -> `container` -> `row-fluid` but input fields are not wrapped nicely inside either using row or row-fluid.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTXa7/)

Why would it not handle properly by default?
And, how do I get around this?

I can use pre-defined Bootstrap classes such as input-large, input-xlarge and put custom
padding around container or row but it is not an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/FTXa7/6/

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:black;">

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
                <label>test</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level">
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <label>test</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level">
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <label>test</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level">
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <label>test</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level">
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

When you use the fluid-container, you don't need to put also the fixed container.
Also, with Bootstrap you should avoid explicitly defining width on elements: use the grid and css classes, otherwise you will have strange results.

An input element can be converted to a block element with the class "input-block-level" (do not use width=100% because Bootstrap uses negative margins to place elements on the grid and that will not work, as you could see).

**PLUS: example using nested rows in fluid grids:**

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:black;">

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span10 offset1">

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <label>test</label>
                        <input type="text" class="input-block-level">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

By using the fluid grid (12 columns) and offsets, you can get almost any layout you want. The example above shows a way to center a fluid element inside another one, by using offset.

`span10` + `offset1` = 11 columns.
So you still have 1 column on the right: this is centered.

REMEMBER: every row has 12 columns, starting from left.

12 columns is 100%, 9 = 75%, 6 = 50%, 3 = 25%, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that. The reason I added `container` inside `container-fluid` was because the application I am creating template for requires custom width that is 90% of the width of `container-fluid` which is 100%. Any better idea on getting around this? Thanks very much!

Comment: I edited the answer to show you an example. This is always the same principle: use the grid and nest elements to get any kind of layout.

Comment: This is excellent stuff! I never thought of doing it this way. Thanks very much :)

Comment: This is the way bootstrap fluid grid was intended, which is slightly different from the fixed grid. As you know, a bootstrap layout can have a lot of rows and spans nested but if you do it this way, the layout is consistent and much easier to maintain. Note that spans should ONLY have rows as their parents (never other spans).